# Classify the critical point $x=2$ of $f(x)=(x-2)^{17}\left(x+5\right)^{24}$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

**Question**

> Let $f(x)=(x-2)^{17}(x+5)^{24}$. Then is $x=2$ a maximum, minimum, or neither?

**Book's Approach**

> $f'''\left(2\right)\ne 0$. S
>   Since the odd integral derivative of the function is non-zero, $x=2$ is neither a minimum nor maximum

**Please Explain**

How did they conclude odd integral derivative
of the function is non-zero?

$f'''(2)\ne 0$ it is $2^{nd}$derivative. I don't how they did it.

Comment: The book is totally wrong. $f''(2)=0$ for sure. What does the graph of $x^{17}$ look like near $x=0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Note it's $f'''$

Comment: Oh, doesn't matter. The first sixteen derivatives of $f$ are all $0$ at $x=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $f(2)=0$ and just check the values of $f$ near $2$. If $x<2$ then $f(x) <0$ and if $x>2$ then $f(x) >0$. Thus the point $x=2$ is neither a minimum nor a maximum of $f$. We don't need derivatives for such simple problems.

Answer (score 3):

The hint:

For $x>2$ we have $f(x)>0$ and for $x<2$ around $2$ we have $f(x)<0$.

Comment: This is same as my answer but just a few seconds late. I guess you were typing when my answer arrived.

Answer (score -1):

Just a typo in the book. Should say: $f''(2)=0$, therefore neither maximum, nor minimum.

```
   f"(x) < 0 - local maximum
   f"(x) > 0 - local minimum
   f"(x) = 0 (your case)- neither of those
```

Comment: The third case means you can't decide whether there is a maximum or a minimum. It is possible that there is a minimum or maximum even if second derivative vanishes. For example consider $f(x) =x^{4}$ and $0$ is a minimum yet $f''(0)=0$.